# How to hide child items for a particular group in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

My `ExpandableListView` has always single children for a particular group. For some groups I'd like to hide child items however I'd like the group to be still clickable (every group item after click changes it's layout). So what should be returned for such groups from `getChildView`?

Comment: don't populate that within your adapter give some restrictions that if `child == childpostion` leave

Comment: @Virus I don't catch you idea, can you elaborate?

Comment: OKay let's say you have your adapter class for the `expandablelistview` right? so within the `getchild()` perform for `condition` checking , if you are populating the data from database within the quesry make some `constraints` or else simple give some condition which won't set true for that particular child

Comment: You still didn't get to me :) but an answer would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried out the answer given my `simas`?

Comment: yes and actually it even works but I was wondering about your solution

Comment: it's the same.. the only thing that i said is of `constraints` like if you are making bit complicated app where you have specific fields to chose from and based on it you want to show/hide the child

Comment: actually mine app is complicated and the condition not to show child is quite complicated... also you mentioned using getChild() method and this is why I was interested in your answer, maybe you can post some of your code as answer?

Comment: By that i meant to say `getchildview()` ok i will upload the code but i am not sure if it works

Comment: are you using database??

Comment: if you are using database than use `cursor` to put some constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `getChildrenCount` and for your wanted groups return 0, as if they don't have children. They will still be clickable though.

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if (groupPosition == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return super.getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i think, the code is not tested

```
public view getChildView(int groupPosition, int ChildPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
if(!groupPostion)//for the group you dont want the layout to be displayed
v=your custom view for the child items.//or if you know the exact position define it like 
//if or use switch (groupPosition==something){v.setVisibility(View.GONE)}
return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [collapseGroup()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#collapseGroup(int)). Also in your constructor you need your ExpandableListView

```
public class YourExapandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    int mLastExpandedGroupPosition = -1;

    public YourExapandableAdapter(Context context, ExpandableListView expandableListView) {
            mContext = context;
            mExpandableListView = expandableListView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
        if(groupPosition != mLastExpandedGroupPosition){
                mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(mLastExpandedGroupPosition);
        }

        mLastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }
```

In this case I hide last group, but you can the current group or whatever you want.